# Pushing data from MSSQL into Salesforce

Tags: integration, data, sqlserver, data-synchronization

Are there any best practices or recommendations for syncing licence data from our MSSQL database to Salesforce custom objects which are child objects of Accounts?

As a SaaS app, customers can sign up by credit card online which is updated in our licence table. We're looking to push changes in this database to Salesforce and have Apex triggers run on the changed data.

Options seem to be tools like Jitterbit, or we write a C# application to connect between our database and Salesforce and run it on a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C# as an option you could write a CRL trigger to update Salesforce via the API. 
Creating a CRL Trigger
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/938d9dz2(v=vs.100).aspx

Connecting to SFDC from .NET
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/11/nothing-net-connected-service.html